# Can't assign state to new state by .filter - react-redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Let's assume that:

```
initialState = [
 {
  text: "Hello",
  id: 0,
  done: false
 },
 {
  text: "World",
  id: 1,
  done: true
 }
]
```

I create an action creator to delete a todo task that has done === true

```
deleteCompleted: state => {
            state = state.filter(task => task.done === false);
        }
```

Instead of reassigning the state to only the task that has id == 0, it returns the recent state.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducers should be returning state rather than updating it

```
deleteCompleted: state => state.filter(task => task.done === false)
```